# What's the difference between /usr/local/lib/python2.6 and /usr/lib/python2.6?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu and noticed these two directories:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages

/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
```

Which one should be used for installing Python packages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ubuntu packages in `.deb` format should use

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
```

Files you install outside the package management, i.e. files `dpkg` is unaware of, should go into

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
```

Se also the [file system hierarchy standard](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man7/hier.7.html).

Comment: @Bertrand: "Should", if you care about standards conformance.