# How to make system see freshly installed Python 2.7.8 on Ubuntu 12.04 (precise)

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, package-management

**Summary:** Several utilities do not work after I installed more recent python on my Ubuntu machine. Why?

My only experience with Linux is Ubuntu 12.04 and so far I've relied on apt-get primarily for installing packages (i.e. very little experience with ./configure && make && sudo make install).

More recent versions of python do not appear to be available via apt-get, so I downloaded installed python 2.7.8 with your typical

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Now, I have essentially zero knowledge of package management, so with that in mind...

For whatever reason I had to manually replace the python symbolic link in /usr/bin with the appropriate reference to the new binary (I thought install would do this). I still have python 2.7.3 on my machine, by the way.

i.e.

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo rm python
ln -s /location/of/new/python python
```

Now, in preparation for writing a totally different question, I wanted to confirm my version of Ubuntu with

```
lsb_release -a
```

but I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 26, in <module>
    import lsb_release
ImportError: No module named lsb_release
```

I get the sense that this will keep happening with lots of utilities until I can tell my system somehow to see the ubuntu installed (apt-get) python modules.

For example, I had pip installed and working, but now if I type

```
pip install lsb_release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

Is there an easy (or not) way to resolve all these dependency problems?

I now have IDLE working (running) with the new Python 2.7.8 after installing tk-dev

```
sudo apt-get install tk-dev
```

(it was previously working without this step)

but if I open a python script with IDLE **by right clicking and going to IDLE** it cannot see my wxPython (wx) libraries, which I've also freshly built. I had this problem from the terminal also but resolved it according to

https://sites.google.com/site/opensourceconstriubtions/ettl-martin-1/tutorials/how-to-solve-following-error-when-starting-a-wxwidgets-application-libwx_gtk2u_adv-3-x-so-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory

How can I get IDLE to see the wx modules when I right click on a python file and go to IDLE? If I run IDLE from the terminal it *can* see the wx module (i.e. `import wx`   works).

I know this question is all over the place but I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks.

**Additional information that might be relevant:**

```
which python
/usr/bin/python

python --version
Python 2.7.8

python -m site
sys.path = [
'/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/local/lib/python27.zip',
'/home/jpf/src/Python-2.7.8/Lib',
'/home/jpf/src/Python-2.7.8/Lib/plat-linux2',
'/home/jpf/src/Python-2.7.8/Lib/lib-tk',
'/home/jpf/src/Python-2.7.8/Lib/lib-old',
'/home/jpf/src/Python-2.7.8/build/lib.linux-i686-2.7',
'/home/jpf/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.9.4-gtk2',
]
```

(This correctly has two versions of wxPython installed.)
But here's where it looks inconsistent to me...

```
locate lsb_release.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lsb_release.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lsb_release.pyc
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py
/usr/share/pyshared/lsb_release.py
```

The location of python module lsb_release is `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` while python appears to be searching in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. What did I do wrong?

**Partial Answer**

Beginning to understand the issue, and as expected it is due to my ignorance of how Linux and Ubuntu work.

When in Ubuntu the administrator installs a given python related *python-module* via `sudo apt-get install python-module` it is placed in `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages`. When the admin installs a python *program* via the same method it appears to be located in the `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages`. For example, when I installed pip I installed via `sudo apt-get install python-pip`. This created the directory `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip`. When I installed `xlwt` with pip, a directory `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages/xlwt` was created. This may not be a hard and fast rule, but it seems that at least python modules, when installed with either apt-get or pip are all installed in `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages`.

This is contrasted with the **site-packages** location `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` (`/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` doesn't exist), to which packages are added when the admin installs a package manually as I did with wxPython 3.0 (see `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2` above, as distinct from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.9.4-gtk2` which I installed with special instructions to integrate into Ubuntu's package manager).

This is described here:

[What's the difference between dist-packages and site-packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages)

Related is the difference between `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib` described here:

[What's the difference between /usr/local/lib/python2.6 and /usr/lib/python2.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315714/whats-the-difference-between-usr-local-lib-python2-6-and-usr-lib-python2-6)

The freshly installed Python 2.7.8 did not "see" the directory `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` which includes the necessary module `lsb_release` because it was not set up to see it via the package manager (via `apt-get`). Since I installed it manually (i.e. with `./configure && make && make install`) it saw only `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/`.

I'd erase this question but maybe it will be helpful to some other newbie. Admins please feel free to erase if appropriate.

Comment: Maybe this post help you:

<http://askubuntu.com/questions/339569/how-to-install-a-python-module-to-the-non-default-python>

Martin